# Did Cherubim have actual faces?

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh, cherubim

What are the opinions on how the faces of the Cherubim actually look like:

- Were they truly human, and if yes whose face (Abraham, Yaakov or else), or
- did they only resemble human faces, or
- did they only have like a button for the nose to know the faces direction, or
- they didn't have faces at all (smooth ball of gold or something)?

Answer (score 4):

Bava Basra 99a states clearly that they were in the form of children:

> תניא אונקלוס הגר אמר כרובים (דברי הימים ב ג, י) מעשה צעצועים הן
>
> It was taught in a Braisa: Onkelos the convert said, the Keruvim were of the form of children.

Rashbam to this Gemara makes reference to Sukkah 5b, which similarly indicates this way.

The Gemara there first notes that the Keruvim indeed had faces. In context, it is trying to find the size of the “face” of the Aron’s lid. One such comparison brought:

> ונילף מכרוב דכתיב (שמות כה, כ) אל הכפורת יהיו פני הכרובים
>
> And let us derive it from the Keruvim, as it is written, “Toward the lid will the *faces* of the Keruvim be.”

Several lines later, the Gemara addresses what their faces looked like:

> ומאי כרוב א"ר אבהו כרביא שכן בבבל קורין לינוקא רביא
>
> What is a Keruv? R’ Avahu said, [the word means] “like a child” [keravia], for in Bavel they call a child a “ravia.”

While this doesn’t address how detailed they were, it does indicate A) that they had actual faces, and B) that they were in the form of children. In other words: I’m not sure which of your first two bullet points is correct, but it’s certainly one of those two.

Comment: How do you see from this gemara that the actual faces of the keruvim were any more face-like than that of the kaporet itself? Perhaps כרביא is describing some other property, e.g. size or form, of the overall structure? It's probably worth adding the next line of gemara...

Comment: First I appreciate your attempt to deal with the question. I tend to agree with @loewian that the Gemorrah does not say anything specific about the faces, as per my 4 options. Maybe their proportions (size of the head) were those of children, but the faces were simply flat.

Comment: (I +1ed for the attempt, not that this really answers the question)